# Is this normal behaviour for a cat?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, desexing, reproduction

My cat has been acting very strange today and wonder if this is normal behavior or if something is wrong.

I have 2 cats, one is male and one is female. The male one has been neutered. So the female shouldn't be pregnant. The female has not yet been spayed. They are both roughly 8 months old.

Since this morning the female cat has been acting very strange. I noticed she was lowering the front half of her body to the ground and sticking her bum into the air while tapping her back feet back and forward. At first, I assumed she was maybe going through heat or something and was trying to get the male cat to have sex with her (which he showed no interest to, obviously), but now I am starting to get a little worried. She has been doing this all day, as much as possible, while making whimpering sounds and having small tremors. It seems like she is in some discomfort. She has been very active today and even when relaxing she is still holding her bum in the air. She has also been craving a lot of attention from me, cuddling into me as much as possible, which is not like her. Normally she likes to be on her own.

Is this normal? Was I correct and she is just going through heat? Her strange behavior is really worrying me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all the symptoms point to the direction that your cat is in heat. Still to rule out any possible underlying medical condition do visit a vet.

Cats in heat give some difficult time to owners. If you think that you can't handle all the difficulties go for spaying your cat.

Also if you have no plans for having some kitten, spaying helps a cat prevent many future medical complications that may arise. One of the most common is cats which are not spayed but are unable to reproduce after multiple heat cycles may develop cyst in uterus requiring emergency surgery.